# How to disable jquery autocomplete without losing result?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i disable the jquery autocomplete in input field without losing the result in the dropdown list.

Example: when the user types "8 bd" I have as a result from an API that contains "8 boulv", I want to display the result even if they don't match with the string  "8 bd"

```
jQuery("#myField").autocomplete({
        source: resp.resultList
});
```

Comment: Your question title and description does not match.

Comment: Also JAVA is not JavaScript

Comment: I guess that should be possible, if you use a function for `source`, https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source - then _you_ are in charge of what "matches" this returns, for the currently entered term. (How exactly you want to match `8 bd` with `8 boulv`, that part is up to you though.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is somewhat similar thing.
I have used https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-similarity plugin to match strings.

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Clojure",
    "8 boulv"
  ];
  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: function(req, resp) {
      var q = req.term;
      var myResponse = [];
      $.each(availableTags, function(key, item) {
        if (stringSimilarity.compareTwoStrings(item.toLowerCase(), q.toLowerCase()) > 0) {
          myResponse.push(item);
        }
      });
      resp(myResponse);
    },
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/string-similarity/umd/string-similarity.min.js"></script>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/codething/tcq9wrnp/11/

Comment: As @CBroe mentioned in the above comment. You can take this as initial input and customise the function according to your need.

Comment: Well, I can do that. But i find it easier to have working example this way.

Comment: Personal preference.. :) Edited.

Comment: Thanks @CodeThing but do you have another solution without this library**string-similarity**